# LINQ OrderBy and Where combined

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to avoid multiple checks of `DistanceTo` method in the following situation:

```
public IEnumerable<Object> NearbyObjects => Objects.Where(o => a.DistanceTo(o) < 10).OrderBy(o => a.DistanceTo(o));
```

or

```
public IEnumerable<Object> NearbyObjects => Objects.OrderBy(o => a.DistanceTo(o)).TakeWhile(o => a.DistanceTo(o) < 10);
```

In any case I have to use `DistanceTo` method two times. Is possible to avoid this in LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `let` statement in linq query syntax like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Object> NearbyObjects =>
   from o in Objects
   let distanceTo = a.DistanceTo(o) 
   where distanceTo < 10
   orderby distanceTo 
   select o;
```

If you want to use method syntax, you will have to temporarily project to an anonymous type

```
public IEnumerable<Object> NearbyObjects =>
   Objects.Select(o => new { o, distanceTo = a.DistanceTo(o) })
          .Where(o => o.distanceTo < 10)
          .OrderBy(o => o.distanceTo)
          .Select(o => o.o);
```